# Copy a file using Microsoft Graph C# SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to copy a file from a drive to another using the C# SDK for Microsoft Graph, but I get an error that I'm not sure how to handle.

This is my code:

```
public async Task CopyFile(CopyDriveFileCommand c)
{
    var graphClient = CreateDelegatedGraphClient(c.Token);

    var oldDrive = await graphClient
        .Groups[c.OldGroupId]
        .Drive
        .Request()
        .Select("id")
        .GetAsync();

    var parentReference = new ItemReference
    {
        DriveId = oldDrive.Id,
        Id = c.FileToCopyId
    };

    var result = await graphClient
        .Groups[c.NewGroupId]
        .Drive
        .Root
        .ItemWithPath(c.NewPath)
        .Copy("test.png", parentReference)
        .Request()
        .PostAsync();
}
```

And this is the error I get:

> Code: "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"
>
> Message: "The parameter name does not exist in method GetById."

I'm using a hardcoded name now, but I've also tried sending `null` as name parameter in `Copy()` and also the same name as the original file.
I get the same error if I send the original filename.

If I send `null` as name parameter, then I get the same error message, but it says

> "The parameter **parentReference** does not exist in method GetById."

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `parentReference` should contain Ids for the *destination*, not the *source*:

```
var parentReference = new ItemReference
{
    DriveId = "Destination Drive Id",
    Id = "Destination Folder Id"
};
```

You then copy the file by navigating to the source and copying it to the destination:

```
var result = await graphClient
    .Groups[c.OldGroupId]
    .Drive
    .Items[c.FileToCopyId]
    .Copy("test.png", parentReference)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-body):

> Note: The *parentReference* should include the `driveId` and `id` parameters for the **target** folder.

Comment: Thank you, I must have missed that Note in the documentation.

Comment: If you dont know the folders driveitemid but you do know the folder structure or path you want to save to from root then how would you do that?